# how to check date $gte in mongodb for 'dd.mm.YYYY' date format

Tags: mongodb

I want data where deliveryDate is greater than equal to current date but it is not working in mongodb. my deliveryDate are stored in "11.8.2018" this format.

```
collection.aggregate([
{
  $match: {"deliveryDate" : { $gte: new Date(new Date().setDate(new.  Date().getDate()-2)) }
},{
 $group: {
      _id:{
           year: { $year: "$createdDate" },
           month: { $month: "$createdDate" },
           day: { $dayOfMonth: "$createdDate" },
           time: { $dateToString: { format: "%H:%M:%S:%L", date: "$createdDate" }},
           partialAmount : "$partialAmount",
           balanceAmount : "$balanceAmount"
         }
      }
 },
])}
```

but this is not working if I give create date instead of deliveryDate then it is working but I want them according to deliveryDate.

Comment: Is the `deliveryDate` a _string_ data type?

Comment: yes deliveryDate is string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider these two input documents:

```
{ deliveryDate: "11.8.2018" }
{ deliveryDate: "11.12.2019" }
```

Using the following aggregation stages you can filter documents with the delivery date greater than today's date.

```
db.test.aggregate( [ 
{ 
  $addFields: { deliveryDate: { $dateFromString: { dateString: "$deliveryDate", format: "%d.%m.%Y" } } }
},
{
  $match: { deliveryDate: { $gte: ISODate() } }
}
] )
```

Only, the document with `deliveryDate: "11.12.2019"` will be matched (as it is greater than today's date of *30-Nov-2019*).

***- OR -***

You can use the following query filter using the `expr` with `$match`.  The result of comparing dates will be same.

```
var deliveryDtFilter = { $gte: [
  { $dateFromString: { dateString: "$deliveryDate", format: "%d.%m.%Y" } },
  ISODate() 
]};

db.test.aggregate( [ {
  $match: { $expr: { deliveryDtFilter } }
} ] )
```

Answer (score 0):

On modern mongoDB versions (Since version 5.0) you can use `$$NOW` for current date and `$expr` in order to do it with `find` instead of an aggregation pipeline

```
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {$gte: [
      {$dateFromString: {
          dateString: "$deliveryDate",
          format: "%d.%m.%Y"
      }},
      "$$NOW"
  ]}
})
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_rm-jjLi22P)