# Mongo aggregation to find dates $gte 6 months ago, stored as strings in "DD-MM-YYYY" format

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to write a mongo aggregation which returns all records where an email was sent in the last 6 months. The `emailSentDate` field is stored (annoyingly) in the format `DD-MM-YYYY`.

I've been looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59117819/20350660) from a similar question, but I can't get it to work. Can anybody help point me in the right direction?

What I have so far:

**Mongo Data**
The data is stored in this format. There are obviously a bunch more fields which I've omitted as they're not relevant.

```
{
    "admin": {
        "emailSentDate": "11-06-2023"
    },
    "data": {
      // More data here
    }

}
```

**My code so far**

```
const now = new Date();
const sixMonthsAgoDate = now.setMonth(now.getMonth() - 6);


const data = await MyModel.aggregate(
[
      {
        $addFields: {
          "admin.emailSentDate" : {$dateFromString: {dateString: "$admin.emailSentDate", format: "%d-%m-%Y"}}
        }
      },
      {
        $match: {"admin.emailSentDate": {$gte: sixMonthsAgoDate} }
      }
    ]
)
```

I'm not getting any data back, just an empty array. Can anybody see what I'm doing wrong here?

Edit: I am using mongo version 4.13.0 and cannot use `$dateSubtract` as suggested in one of the answers.

Thanks

Comment: Your date is older than 6 months ago. It is about 11 months ago. This email was not sent during the last 6 months

Comment: @nimrodserok That is just an example. The collection has thousands of documents which should match. I have edited it to help the confusion

Comment: Still not in range. When in range it is working

Comment: It is not working. I have data from yesterday, the day before etc that it is not finding.

Comment: Check out the [mongoDB playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BOE0EmGILFq)

Comment: If it is not working for you, can you provide a non-working example on the playground?

Comment: Nimrod, you are correct and I have accepted your previous answer. I had a spelling mistake which was breaking my code. *facepalm*. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to do everything inside the query, without date manipulation on `js`. You can also use `find` instead of an aggregation pipeline:

```
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {$gte: [
      {$dateFromString: {
          dateString: "$admin.emailSentDate",
          format: "%d-%m-%Y"
      }},
      {$dateSubtract: {
          startDate: "$$NOW",
          unit: "month",
          amount: 6
      }}
  ]}
})
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/uVmv9dPZyik)

**EDIT:**
For mongoDB versions older than 5.0, the suggested approach from the question should work. See [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BOE0EmGILFq)

Comment: A very nice answer. Sadly, I am using an older version of mongodb (4.13.0) - $dateSubtract is only for version 5 onwards. Sorry, I should have mentioned